# npm start command changing all files in git

Tags: git, angular

I make a couple of changes in one (.ts) file and do npm start. it is supposed to return me with 3 files(1 .ts,1 .js and 1 .map)  in total that changed in git. but its returning with truck load of files got changed in Git. Why? those files are not changed at all actually but they appear changed in git. this is happening in vs 2015.

Comment: what's the output of `git status`?

Comment: its something like changes to be committed. below answers helped me. Thanks

Comment: why did i get negative votes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your `.gitignore` file:

```
# Project Files  
**/src/**/*.js   
**/src/**/*.map  
**/e2e/**/*.js  
**/e2e/**/*.map  


# Destination Folder  
coverage/  
dist/  
docs/  
node_modules/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and specify all the files/directories you don't want git to keep history of.